# JavaScript updating 2d array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to update every element of a 2d array only once. But unexpectedly array item gets update multiple times.

**For example:**

```js
const s = "ab";
const m = [...Array(s.length).fill([...Array(s.length).fill("")])]

for(let row = 0; row < s.length; row++) {
  for (let col = 0; col < s.length; col++) {
    console.log(row, col)
    m[row][col] += `<${row}${col}>`
  }
}

console.log(m)
```

> it should return `m` = `[ [ '<00>', '<01>' ], [ '<10>', '<11>' ] ]`

> but it returns `m` = `[ [ '<00><10>', '<01><11>' ], [ '<00><10>', '<01><11>' ] ]` instead.

Can anyone explain it, please?

> Update:
>
> Here I'm looping through each item once, so there should be no
> chance of updating the item twice ( two value should not concat here )

Answer (score 1):

Instead of initializing array with specific length. You may just initialize empty array then push the elements. Because if you do `+` of 2 strings, it may just concatenate it, for example:

```js
console.log("I "+"am");
```

Full working code:

```js
const s = "ab";
let m = [];

for(let row = 0; row < s.length; row++) {
  m.push([]);
  for (let col = 0; col < s.length; col++) {
    m[row].push(`<${row}${col}>`);
  }
}

console.log(m);
```

Comment: could you explain what's wrong with my code?

Comment: for some reason, I need to initialize the array before starting the loop

Comment: Your double fill likely does not create what you think it does

Comment: I know plus sign is the problem, but it means somehow array item updating twice, right? but why? @DhanaD.

Comment: I think it's because of the `fill`. Have you tried logging the value of the initialized array before the loop?

Comment: yes, it's simply empty `[ [ '', '' ], [ '', '' ] ]` @DhanaD.

Comment: @Moni When I tried it in this snippet, it didn't return that as you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using `<${row}${col}>`, You should simple use let size=0 and use Array[i][j] = size++;  in place of `<${row}${col}>`

you should use the following way for 2D Arrays

//Create a new 1D array

```
let myArray  = new Array(2);
```

// Loop to create 2D array using 1D array

```
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i] = new Array(2);
}
```

//declare size

```
let size = 0;
```

// Loop to initialize 2D array elements.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        myArray[i][j] = size++;
    }
}
```

// Loop to display the elements of 2D array.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++)    {
        document.write(myArray[i][j] + " ");
    }
    document.write("<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a loop, you can use map instead.

```js
const a = Array(2).fill(null).map(
  (_, row) => Array(2).fill(null).map(
    (_, col) => `<${row}${col}>`
  )
);
```